# wpf binding combobox to enum in different namespace

Tags: wpf, binding, enums, namespaces

I'm trying to bind a XAML ComboBox so that its list items are the members of the System.IO.Ports.Parity enum.

I've found plenty of examples of databinding enums, but it seems these don't work if the enum is in a different namespace (like System.IO.Ports).

Right now I have:

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" x:Key="parityValues">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="System.IO.Ports.Parity" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

But I get the error "Type reference cannot find public type named 'System.IO.Ports.Parity'."

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding something like

```
xmlns:sysioports="clr-namespace:System.IO.Ports;assembly=System"
```

and then changing the `<x:Type />` line to

```
<x:Type TypeName="sysioports:Parity" />
```

Should make it work.

Comment: I managed to figure out all of this except for the "sysioports:Parity" part.  Couldn't find where this was documented...

Answer (score 4):

just because you should include and use namespace like this

```
<Window xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:System.IO.Ports.Parity;assembly=SampleLibrary">
...
  <x:Type TypeName="custom:Parity" />
...
</Window>
```