# Enum being from imported namespace bound to ListBox cannot be found

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have spent a lot of time looking at code for binding enums to listboxs, and i am fine doing it when:

1. the enum within the same namespace as the XAML
2. the enum is in a name space that starts with Windows.etc....
   However, I have an enum that is contained within a namespace namespace that is Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Nui:

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
       <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues"
                       ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
                       x:Key="Joints">
           <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
               <x:Type TypeName="JointID" />
           </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
       </ObjectDataProvider>
   </Window.Resources>
   ```

   At the line where I set the type of the method parameter, I get an error

> Type 'JointID' not found

I know it will something to do with setting the clr-namespace path:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:mic="clr-namespace:Microsoft;assembly=Microsoft.Research.Kinect"
```

(the assembly that manages the API is Microsoft.Research.Kinect.dll)
But when I do this I get an error:

> Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'Microsoft' that is not included in the assembly.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:mic="clr-namespace:Microsoft;assembly=Microsoft.Research.Kinect"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YOUR NAMESPACE" >
   <Window.Resources>
      <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues"
                          ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
                          x:Key="Joints">
         <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type Type="{x:Type local:JointID" />
         </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
      </ObjectDataProvider>
   </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Try binding the type. You'll have to add your namespace at the top and the enum will have to be public. Then I think you should be able to reference it.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx) explains you need to use a prefix to specify the right xml/xaml namespace. You also need to define the new namespace and make sure you specify the correct assembly and .net namespace.

```
xmlns:kin="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Nui;assembly=Microsoft.Research.Kinect"
```

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
                    x:Key="Joints">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="kin:JointID" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

PS: Also see [wpf binding combobox to enum in different namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138573/wpf-binding-combobox-to-enum-in-different-namespace)